# Real version of the Jensen's formula.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, vector-spaces, harmonic-analysis

Prove the Jensen's formula

> $$\int_{T}f(z+re^{2\pi i\theta})d\theta-f(z)=\iint_{D(z,r)}\log{\frac{r}{|w-z|}}\Delta f(w)dm(w)$$
>   where $w$ is in $D(z,r)$ and $f$ is a two-dimensional $C^2$  function.

You may notice that if $f$ is a harmonic function, the equality is the maximum principle. For the simplicity, put $r=1$, $z=0$. Then it is equal to

> $$\int_{T}f(e^{2\pi i\theta})d\theta-f(0)=-\iint_{D(0,1)}(\log{|w|})\Delta f(w)dm(w)$$

By the Green's second identity,
$$\iint_{D(0,1)}(\log{|w|})\Delta f(w)dm=\int_{D(0,1)}f(w)\Delta \log{|w|}dm+\int_{\partial D}\log{|w|}\frac{d}{dn}f(w)d\sigma-\int_{\partial D}f(w)\frac{d}{dn}\log{|w|}d\sigma$$

Since $\log{|w|}$ is the harmonic function, the first term on the right side is always $0$. The second term is also $0$ because $\log{|w|}=0$ on the unit disc. Therefore,
$$\iint_{D(0,1)}(\log{|w|})\Delta f(w)dm=-\int_{\partial D}f(w)\frac{d}{dn}\log{|w|}d\sigma$$
Let's calculate the left term.
$$\int_{\partial D}f(w)\frac{d}{dn}\log{|w|}d\sigma=\int_{\partial D}f(w)(\triangledown \log{|w|} \cdot n )d\sigma =\int_{0}^{1} f(e^{2\pi i\theta})[(\cos(2\pi \theta),\sin(2\pi \theta)) \cdot (\cos(2\pi \theta),\sin(2\pi \theta))]=\int_{0}^{1}f(e^{2\pi i\theta})d\theta$$
In conclusion, we get
$$\int_{T}f(e^{2\pi i \theta})d\theta =-\iint_{D(0,1)}(\log{|w}|)\Delta f(w)dm(w)$$
I need your sharp eyes. I fail to find my mistake.

Comment: I find it! $\Delta \log{|w|}$ is the dirac delta function!